# Laravel 6.0 - Decreasing Product Quantity - Route [cart.update] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, routes, e-commerce

I have a method for increasing the quantity of a product with a click of a button. It works perfectly. I'm calling the Cart object from this GitHub package here:

```
Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;
```

Here's the code:

```
// CartController.php
public function update(Request $request, $rowId)
    {
        $product = Cart::get($rowId);
        Cart::update($rowId, $product->qty + 1);

        return back()->with('quantityIncreasedMessage', 'Product quantity has been increased.');
    }
```

```
// cart.blade.php
{{-- INCREASE PRODUCT QUANTITY --}}
                      <td class="border-0 align-middle">
                        <form action="{{ route('cart.update', $product->rowId) }}" 
                        method="POST">
                          @csrf
                          @method('PATCH')
                          <strong>{{ $product->qty }}</strong>
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <button>+</button>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                      </td>
{{-- END INCREASE PRODUCT QUANITITY --}}
```

I want to do something almost identical with my method for decreasing the product quantity. Here's the code:

```
// CartController.php
public function decreaseQuantity(Request $request, $rowId)
    {
        $product = Cart::get($rowId);
        Cart::update($rowId, $product->qty - 1);

        return back()->with('quantityDecreasedMessage', 'Product quantity has been increased.');
    }
```

```
// cart.blade.php
{{-- DECREASE PRODUCT QUANTITY --}}
                      <td class="border-0 align-middle">
                        <form action="{{ route('cart.decreaseQuantity', $product->rowId) }}" 
                        method="POST">
                          @csrf
                          @method('PATCH')
                          <strong>{{ $product->qty }}</strong>
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <button>-</button>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      {{-- END DECREASE PRODUCT QUANITITY --}}
```

I'm not sure why, but I get this error message: `Route [cart.update] not defined.` when implementing this method and trying to access my cart page. As I said, the code of the two methods are almost identical.

I find this strange as I have both my named routes clearly defined here:

```
// web.php
// increases product quantity
Route::patch('/cart/{rowId}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update');
// decreases product quantity
Route::patch('/cart/{rowId}', 'CartController@decreaseQuantity')->name('cart.decreaseQuantity');
```

Comment: did you try changing route name? something like this Route::patch('/cart/update/{rowId}

Comment: It is because of your identical route

Comment: @Poldo @Jseelb I now have this: ```Route::patch('/cart/increase/{rowId})``` and ```Route::patch('/cart/decrease/{rowId})```. It works now. Thank you both!

Comment: @HarrisonGreeves change route urls, Laravel doesn't allow two or more same URL.
'/cart/{rowId}', '/cart/{rowId}' this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

don't call 2 function with same url.

```
// web.php
// increases product quantity
Route::patch('/cart/increase/{rowId}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update');
// decreases product quantity
Route::patch('/cart/decrease/{rowId}', 'CartController@decreaseQuantity')->name('cart.decreaseQuantity');
```